# Negative margin in percent not same width

Tags: html, css

I am curious: If I give the parent element a margin of X, and the inner element a margin of -X, how come these two don't add up to the same size?

```css
.outer{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 3%;
}
.inner{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 -3%;
}
.another{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="another"></div>
```

I would have expected them to work exactly the same as with viewport units:

```css
.outer{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 3vw;
}
.inner{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 -3vw;
}
.another{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="another"></div>
```

Comment: % of what? For margin a % means the % of the parent's width.

Comment: You will get the right result if you specify `width:100%` of the divs.

Comment: because you are using `3%` doesn't mean they are equal. each 3% has its own reference

Comment: To add to A Haworth's answer, the % is based on the actual parent width. The outer element is calculted from the body element, the inner is calculated from the outer's width. Because the body and outer widths are different the 3%-of-those-values are different. Hope this helps.